# Expansion of Excel's "subtotals" (or other) feature

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Regularly a question appears here (or [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724911)) which could be answered by expanding the "subtotals" feature (like in the case of [the StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724911) using `CONCATENATE` or `TEXTJOIN` as the "subtotals" function.

Are there any plans of expanding the "subtotals" feature in Excel?
More general: is there an official site where Microsoft shows the future plans for its MS-Office tools (Excel, Word, ...)?

Comment: Roadmap for Office is shown [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=)

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: If you don't find any new features plan in the web, you can also try to give feedback or suggestion. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11